# Cakephp 3.0 Save associated model

Tags: cakephp, save, model-associations, cakephp-3.0, associated-object

I am learning cakePHP 3.0 and have some problem with saving associated data on my model.

I try to save a Client with associated data of ClientPreferences

**ClientTable**

```
class ClientsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        (...)
        $this->belongsTo('ClientPreferences', [
            'foreignKey' => 'client_preferences_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ClientController**

```
$aClient = $this->Clients->newEntity();
$aClient = $this->Clients->patchEntity($aClient, $this->request->data);

$aClientPreference = $this->Clients->ClientPreferences->newEntity();
$aClientPreference->my_field = 'my value';

$aClient->ClientPreferences = $aClientPreference;

$this->Clients->save($aClient, ['associated' => ['ClientPreferences']];
```

The Client entity is correctly saved, but not the associated ClientPreferences entity and there is no error thrown by Cake.

I have tried to follow this : 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations

But haven't find any issue to do it properly. 
Do anybody have an advice ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Conventions, conventions, conventions

There's clearly a difference in the examples that you've linked, take a closer look at the property names, and if you scroll down a little further, you'll find an explanation specifically for `belogsTo` associations.

> When saving belongsTo associations, the ORM expects a single nested entity at the singular, underscored version of the association name. For example:
>   [...]

**[Cookbook > Saving Data > Saving BelongsTo Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongsto-associations)**

So for `belongsTo` associations, the property name is by default expected to be lowercased and underscored, ie `$aClient->client_preference`.

Your foreign key should btw. be singular too in order to match the conventions, ie `client_preference_id`, even though it's just the property name causing the  problem.

See also **[Cookbook > Associations > BelongsTo Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)** (especially the `foreignKey` and `propertyName` options)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but in my case i am not submitting the form. I my project i am preparing the array manually. But it save my main table data and not of associated table data. Please suggest

Comment: thanks @ndm. As usual helpful for cakePHP!

Answer (score 0):

If you have additional joinedData to save check this out:
[Cakephp 3 - Save associated belongsToMany (joinTable)](https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/cakephp-3-save-associated-belongstomany-jointable/2685)

There is no explanation in the manual about this!